# Multiple arguments in parameter in def_name() and function's name as variable

Tags: python

To further learn things about parameters and functions, I produced this to ask you guys. This is python 3.4.

```
def menu():
    print ("Your options are the following:")
    print ("1 - k")
    print ("2 - e")
    print ()
    ans = input("Please enter the number: ")
    if ans is '1':
        start('Ktest')

    elif ans is '2':
        start('Etest')

    else: 
        print ("Error - invalid choice")
        print (" ")
    menu()


def start(choose):        
    test = input("Please choose. 1, 2 or 3")
    if test is '1':
        choose('1')
        choose(thing)
    elif test is '2':
        choose('2')
        choose1(thing)
    elif test is '3':
        choose('3')
        choose(thing)
    else:
        print ("Error - invalid choice")
        print (" ")
    menu()

def Ktest(thing):    
    w = thing + 30
    print (w)

def Etest(thing):
    e = thing + 15
    print (w)


menu()
```

So I just tested things just from scratch.

When you press 1 in menu() you would set arguments in start() into Ktest.

What i tried to do was give 'choose' the value of 'Ktest'.

Ktest is a name of the function so in start() I tried to give a value to the argument in the parameter of Ktest(), so I did choose('1'), after that, I wanted to call the function Ktest. However, it says:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

at choose('1'). Does this mean you can't use variable to call functions?

Comment: Did you mean e.g. `start(Etest)`? Note no quotes, that should be the **name**, not a **string literal**.

Comment: oh,, should i get rid of '' sign?

Comment: The `"` sign is a quote mark; yes, you should get rid of them around `Ktest` and `Etest`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried it, i don't think it still counts thing as Ktest. it says thing is not defined

Comment: Well where *is* `thing` supposed to come from?! It's only defined as a parameter of `Etest` and `Ktest`, so it's not available in `start`. Your code makes very little sense.

Comment: When i try do choose(thing) to call the functions, it makes assigns 'thing' to argument in Ktest(thing) which causes error saying thing is not defined

Comment: That is not *at all* how Python works. `thing` doesn't magically get defined in `start` because `Ktest` used that name for the `'1'` value passed as an argument. If you want access to that back in `start`, `Ktest` should `return thing` and `start` should include `thing = Ktest('1')`.

Comment: What i'm trying to do it, use only start() function to call either Ktest or Etest. Of course i can just make start1() just for Etest and use Start() for Ktest, but i want to know if you can just use one function to call either one of them

Comment: Yes, you can pass a function as an argument to `start`, **that's not the problem**. It is **not clear** where you expect the name `thing` to be defined inside `start`; that name being used inside e.g. `Ktest` **does not** make it available in `start`. I suggest you read e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. Also, note that e.g. `ans is '1'` should be `ans == '1'` - identity is not an appropriate test here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transfer function as an argument write this:

```
start(Etest)
```

and

```
start(Ktest)
```

Try a simple example:

```
def menu():
    ans = input("Please enter the number: ")
    if ans == '1':
        start(Ktest)
    else:
        start(Etest)


def start(choosen_func):
    number = input("Please choose. 1, 2 or 3: ")
    choosen_func(str(number))


def Ktest(arg):
    print("Ktest " + arg)


def Etest(arg):
    print("Etest " + arg)


menu()
```

Comment: what you mean? Etest and Ktest is different thing

Comment: You shouldn't test strings by identity - use equality (`if ans == '1':`).

Comment: @SvichkarevAnatoly no, you haven't

Comment: @jonrsharpe My mistake, I thought of something else. Thank you corrected me.